# Executing JavaCC parser more than once

Tags: static, javacc

I am using Eclipse and JavaCC plugin 1.5.27

I want to use the parser to be executed more than only once. It goes perfect, if using only once. Running the parser within the program a second time I get an error:

```
ERROR: Second call to constructor of static parser.  
       You must either use ReInit() or set the JavaCC option STATIC to false
       during parser generation.
```

I add the `ReInit()` after parsing, but this does not help.

This is the code snipped.

```java
public static void myParser(String toanalyze) throws ParseException
{
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( toanalyze.getBytes() );
    SQLwhereS parser = new SQLwhereS(is);
    // .....
    SQLwhereS.one_line();
    // .....
    ReInit(is);
}
```

Comment: I generally use nonstatic parsers.  Then the issue of reinitializing does not come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I generally use nonstatic parser.  The following "Answer" is more a guess than an authoritative answer.  If you try it, please comment, so others (and I) can know whether it's right.

```
static SQLwhereS parser = null ;

public static void myParser(String toanalyze) throws ParseException
{
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( toanalyze.getBytes() );
    if( parser==null) parser = new SQLwhereS(is); else ReInit(is) ;
    .....
    SQLwhereS.one_line();
    .....
```

}

Comment: dear theodore, you made my day. yes, that's it. i think your posting will help a lot in the future, because till now i didn't find a real answer. of course i did also play around with static = false in the options field, but than i run into other problems. this is a great solution. kind regards, hans