# You must either use ReInit() or set the JavaCC option STATIC to false

Tags: parsing, testing, javacc

I'm trying to test my project but when I try to do it parts I've have received this error:

`Second call to constructor of static parser. You must either use ReInit() or set the JavaCC option STATIC to false during parser generation.`

It happens because I need to execute a ReUnit command to update the reference to the new value.

I updated the code, just like it was suggested, with the command ReInit(), but now I have a error (NullPointerException). At this line, `Imp1Parser.ReInit(stream)`, the error happens and stop the execution.

Could someone help me?

Comment: If the line `Imp1Parser.ReInit(stream)` causes a `NullPointerException`, then `Imp1Parser` is `null`. Find out why it's `null`.

Comment: I changed the javacc option static to false and it works well.

Comment: Yeah. I usually use nonstatic parsers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737697/javacc-you-must-either-use-reinit-or-set-the-javacc-option-static-to-false?rq=1